# info.plist merge not showing conflicts

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, info.plist

im trying to merge the main branch into my personal development branch in Xcode. When I do this (for reference), I'm going to the top, switching to the main development branch, then selecting "Merge Into..." and selecting my development branch (blaine_dev). After doing so, it pulls up its normal conflict resolution window and shows all the conflicted files. It's showing the info.plist file as conflicted. When I click the file to resolve conflicts, it shows the development file on the right, but the file on the left is totally blank. it just says "No Editor". Clicking around doesn't do anything at all. When I hit "cancel", for a split second, it reveals both files. then it closes. I'm not sure how to handle this issue. and for reference, going to the command line and trying to merge with git mergetool just shows info.plist as unchanged and unconflicted. although it probably is different than the other because we have a build script that increments the version every time the app is built.

1 more thing. i tried to simply copy and paste one file into the other to resolve conflicts and it didnt change anything. the results are the same.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

any suggestions? im on a deadline

Comment: You can always use terminal + DiffMerge for the conflicts that Xcode can't resolve. The link for set up diffmerge https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__mac.html

Comment: sounds like diffmerge is like mergetool. theyre both on the command line. and using mergetool didnt show any differences or conflicts. i just opened xcode this morning and attempted to merge again, and it worked. it showed the changes. the difference was entirely whitespace